# mobile menu troubles with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, menu

Having some troubles with jquery's `this` selector and what I would guess to be children elements of such. I am trying to make a mobile menu that has different elements, each of which when clicked on, would display a submenu displayed in block format.

HTML

```
 <ul class="mobile" id="mobile-ul">
 <li class="mobile">Category 1
   <ul class="mobile">
   <li class="mobile"><a href="/link1.html">LINK 1</a></li>
   <li class="mobile"><a href="/link2.html">LINK 2</a></li>
   <li class="mobile"><a href="/link3.html">LINK 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="mobile">Category 2
   <ul class="mobile">
   <li class="mobile"><a href="/link1.html">LINK 1</a></li>
   <li class="mobile"><a href="/link2.html">LINK 2</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.mobile{display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; list-style: none; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0; color: #000000;}
ul.mobile li.mobile{display: inline-block; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0; background-color: #FFFFFF; position: relative;}
ul.mobile li.mobile ul.mobile{display: none; visibility: hidden; position: relative;}
ul.mobile li.mobile ul.mobile li.mobile{display: block; padding: 10px 0; background-color: #FFF0F0; width: 100%; text-align: left;}
.li-mobile-open{display: block; visibility: visible; background-color: #000000; color: #FF00FF;}
```

and the JQUERY:

```
$('ul#mobile-ul li').click(function(){
$("ul.mobile", this).toggleClass("li-mobile-on");
});
```

I think it's pretty simple and straight-forward what I am trying to do here, yet it seems to fail no matter what I do. If I replace `toggleClass` with `css({"display":"block"})`, it will in fact work, but of course this is not what I want to do; I want to toggle classes so that when clicked it will display submenu, when clicked again it will hide it.

Hope someone can help me and point out the err in my coding.

Comment: Have you considered `slideToggle`?

Comment: No i have not, not too familiar with its usage. I will investigate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e0gpq0wa/)
Why did you use the same Class on All elements O.o , it a SSSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO bad method , i added category class to your Category so that i can select them

i added !important to both of display and visiblity in the .li-mobile-open

```
.li-mobile-open
{
    display: block !important; 
    visibility: visible !important; 
    background-color: #000000; 
    color: #FF00FF;
}
```

Javascript :

```
$('.category').click(function()
{
    $(this).find("ul.mobile").toggleClass("li-mobile-open");
});
```

Comment: thank you, solved the problem. Apparently I was taught bad coding practices! Thank you for pointing this out, much obliged.